# Why is 'success' on a promise giving me an error that the function doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have some code that looks like this:

```
var db = require("../db.js");

module.exports = {
    init: function(app) {
        // run searchin our database
        app.post("/api/search", function (req, res) {
            // generate search sql
            try {
                var sql_tables = "select attraction.id, title, src from attraction LEFT JOIN attraction_picture ON attraction_picture.attraction_id = attraction.id";
                var sql_group_by = " group by attraction.id";
                var sql_order_by = " ORDER BY ";
                var params = {};

                // order those with pictures first, ALWAYS
                sql_order_by += " if (attraction_picture.id IS NOT NULL, 0, 1), 0";

                // order based on those with higher ratings first
                sql_order_by += " + attraction.stars ";

                // give slight preference to those with more ratings (popularity)
                sql_order_by += " + if (reviews > 5000, 5, reviews/1000) ";

                // apply preferences for each different category independently
                if (typeof(req.body.sess_user.filters) != "undefined") {
                    for (var i in req.body.sess_user.filters) {
                        i = parseInt(i); // make sure its an integer
                        if (!req.body.sess_user.filters[i]) continue;

                        // join to figure out if this attraction matches this filter
                        var thistable = "filter_" + i;
                        sql_tables += " LEFT JOIN attraction_filter " + thistable + " ON " + thistable + 
                            ".attraction_id = attraction.id AND " + thistable + ".filter_id=:filter_id_" + i + " ";
                        params["filter_id_" + i] = i;

                        // if it does match, give points or take away points based on the star. 
                        var adjustment_if_matches = (req.body.sess_user.filters[i]) - 3 * 3; 
                        sql_order_by += " + if(" + thistable + ".attraction_id IS NOT NULL, :filter_adjustment_" + i + ", 0) ";
                        params["filter_adjustment_" + i] = adjustment_if_matches;
                    }
                }

                // per page
                sql_order_by += " DESC LIMIT :start, :per_page";
                params.start = 0;
                if (typeof(req.body.start) != "undefined") {
                    params.start = req.body.start; 
                }
                console.log(req.body.start);
                params.per_page = 24; 

                // execute sql and return results
                app.db.q(sql_tables + sql_group_by + sql_order_by, params).success(function(results) {
                    res.json(results);
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("error running search: ");
                console.log(err);
                res.json([]); // @TODO - better error handling
            }
        });
```

It isn't terribly important what this code does, but essentially it goes through a mysql database and selects certain elements in it.

At this line:

```
// execute sql and return results
                app.db.q(sql_tables + sql_group_by + sql_order_by, params).success(function(results) {
                    res.json(results);
```

I get this error:

```
$ sudo nodemon app.js 
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Listening on port 80
0
passing raw query replacements as the 4th argument to sequelize.query is deprecated. Please use options.replacements instead
error running search: 
TypeError: app.db.q(...).success is not a function
    at /home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/api/attractions.js:54:68
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
    at next (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
    at /home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:305:12)
    at /home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:221:12
    at Function.match_layer (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:288:3)
    at next (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:182:10)
    at /home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:184:16
    at Function.match_layer (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:288:3)
    at next (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:182:10)
    at /home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:184:16
    at Function.match_layer (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:288:3)
    at next (/home/tex/studygit/Planning-App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:182:10)
```

I am very confused as to why this error occurs. This specific function is defined in my `db.js` file that is located in a the parent directory of this file. So it looks something like this:

```
- root
    - directory
         . attractions.js
    . db.js
```

The file I am getting the error on is attractions.js. The definition for the function is, as I stated, located in db.js, which looks like this:

```
// bootstrap the db wrapper
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var conf = require("./conf");

// Database Wrapper Initialization
try {
    if (conf.db.type == "mysql") {
        // connect to database 
        var db = new Sequelize("mysql://" + conf.db.username + ":"+conf.db.password+
            "@" + conf.db.host + ":" + conf.db.port + "/" + conf.db.database);
    } else {
        console.log("PROBLEM - UNKNOWN DB TYPE: " + conf.db.type);
        process.exit(1);
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log("PROBLEM - connecting to db: ");
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
}

// simplified database querying function
db.q = function(query, replace) {
    return this.query(query, null, {raw: true}, replace);
};

module.exports = db; // return our db connection
```

I am just making a simplified query function that is available from the Sequelize module. The sequelize module states:

> public query(sql: string, options: Object): Promise
>   Execute a query on the DB, with the possibility to bypass all the sequelize goodness.
>
> By default, the function will return two arguments: an array of results, and a metadata object, containing number of affected rows etc.
>
> If you are running a type of query where you don't need the metadata, for example a SELECT query, you can pass in a query type to make sequelize format the results:

```
sequelize.query('SELECT...').then(([results, metadata]) => {
  // Raw query - use then plus array spread
});

sequelize.query('SELECT...', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(results => {
  // SELECT query - use then
})
```

If a query is a promise, then why am I not able to use `db.q(...).success` ? Why is it saying the function doesn't exist? Am I doing something wrong here that I am not seeing? I am a little bit new to Javascript so it is likely...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Promises do not have `success` methods. Did you mean to use `.then`? (see the example code at the bottom of your question)

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh my god I'm an idiot.